# Recapthca not displaying in safari

Tags: safari, captcha, recaptcha

Recap isn't displaying on my mac. I am using the recaptcha libraries so I don't know what's going on. Any idea what this could be?

Here is the link: http://txtclub.co/members/register.php

Comment: We need to see some code...

Comment: You *have* to post your code

Comment: I have this same problem here (at the bottom): http://www.jamonit.org/event-registration/?ee=63